# JNI C function cannot be resolved Serial Port Api android

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, serial-port

I'm developing an app for android using serial-port-api. I have installed NDK, downloaded the library and included it. Some functions like SerialPortFinder.getAllDevicesPath() work perfect. But this part of code located in api file **SerialPort.java** is marked red:

```
// JNI
private native static FileDescriptor open(String path, int baudrate, int flags);
public native void close();
public native int getmodemlines();
```

The problem is called

> Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function Java_android_1serialport_1api_SerialPort_open
>   Reports native method declarations in Java where no corresponding JNI function is found in the project.

for all of this three functions.

When I run the project I get an error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileDescriptor android_serialport_api.SerialPort.getFd()' on a null object reference

because the of the previous problem.

**WHAT I HAVE ALREADY DONE**

1. add libserial_port.so like below [image]
2. read all the threads on Stackoverflow about this problem but still no answer.
3. my build.gradle is

```html
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sme.sirius.oelmann.siriussme"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.06"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Gradle version 2.3.0

If somebody could help me I would be very pleased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

As Android Studio didn't see SerialPort.c file, I have just copied and pasted the code to native-lib.cpp and added the SerialPort.h in the same folder (src/main/cpp).

In SerialPort.java I've changed the library call:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}
```

In build.gradle I've returned to default:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

And now it works!